# What did this ATC call mean?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa

[**Audio Clip**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QinX4TcOeex4Ejnl4w4IWJeglQRt_KP2)

There is a rwy 24 in this airport. I'm not sure but the aircraft callsign likes 'TBN3BV'. I tried to find what the aircraft type is but I couldn't. Does somebody know what type of aircraft this is?

The aircraft was approaching to land and had number 3. I think there was traffic close to the aircraft. So the controller said make S-turn for safety...is it correct?

I sometimes make L/R360 or 270 to avoid other traffic but, I've never made S-turn while approaching to land.

I want to know what the controller said because I missed some word and I wonder if I can make S-turn while approaching to land. If I could, should I make two half circle?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They said "TBM" "Three-Bravo-Victor" (3BV). TBM is the [aircraft make, a TBM](http://www.tbm.aero/) and 3BV is the last 3 letters of the callsign.

The maneuver really isn't traffic avoidance so much as exactly what the controller said, spacing. They need to keep a minimum distance between traffic so having the TBM (a fast aircraft) perform an S-turn allows the aircraft in front of it more time to get further away.

Usually if you are in the pattern they will ask for a 360 turn, but if you are in a long straight-in and they just need a little bit of spacing, they will ask for the S-turn. For the S-turn approach you would simply turn 90 degrees to the course, then roll 180 degrees to face the opposite direction, then 180 degrees back around and 90 degrees back on course.

Comment: Thank you. That is TBM! When the aircraft got the landing clearance, it was 8 miles of the airport. That's why the controller have it make S-turn..

Comment: Probably this one: https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=43BV